# Correct code structure when providing REST API access using Zend_Rest_Controller

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, zend-rest

I'm new to Zend Frameworks and MVC type programming (not PHP though) and I'm trying to provide API access to data on my server using the Zend Framework.

I'm using Chris Danielson's article (http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/) as a base.

I want to provide access to data in the following formats:

```
(a) http://www.example.com/api/createevent      
    Data will be POSTed here, success will return an id, otherwise an 
    error message/code

(b) http://www.example.com/api/geteventdetails/1234     
    GET request will return data

(c) http://www.example.com/api/getregistrationdetails/1234  
    GET request will return data

(d) http://www.example.com/api/getregistrationdetails/1234/567  
    GET request will return data
```

Questions:

1. There is a default file which is located at \api\application\controllers\VersionController.php which enables handling of URLs of type: http://www.example.com/api/version . Should I be creating a **separate file** located at: \api\application\controllers\GeteventdetailsController.php which handles requests of type (b) (and one for every type of request)? If not, where should I be placing my code to handle these multiple request types?
2. How can I get the parameters passed in (b) to (d)?
3. To do requests (b) to (d), I need to fetch information from my server's database. Where should I place the code that does the actual MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used routes a lot in ZF, but not the Rest implementation, having swatted up on the docs and on the tutorial you linked to - I will do my best to help you...

It might be worth looking at the docs for the [Rest router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) (about 1/3 down the page) - it explains that it will automatically create routes for you based on the method of the request; so your naming format of *createevent*, *geteventdetails*, etc shouldn't be needed.

**Question 1.**

Rather than creating the file

> \api\application\controllers\GeteventdetailsController.php

I'd create the file

> \api\application\controllers\EventsController.php

This will be one controller to handle all the event actions, be that getting, posting, putting, etc. Your suggestion is too specific for the controller as the get, put, etc will be handled at the action level.

**Question 2.**

The routes described in the docs show you that the final parameter (:id) will be assigned to a parameter in the controller called `id`.

So accessing the URL */events/* using *GET* will invoke the `indexAction()` in your `EventsController.php` file

And accessing the URL */events/99/* using *GET* will invoke the `getAction()` in your `EventsController.php` file. You can access this id from the controller like this

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
```

OR

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->id;
```

You should then write code to query the database for a listing of events or for a specific id. Which brings us nicely on to...

**Question 3.**

Rather than putting the code for querying the database for events into the controller you should create models for your database tables and rows. I'd recommend using the existing setup in ZF for [Zend_Db_Row](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html) and [Zend_Tb_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.table.html) to do this. This will ensure your application/website is MVC.

Putting the code inside the contrller may hinder development later, for example when you write a registation form for an event at a later date in another controller. The logic for creating the event will be duplicated, once in the new controller and once in the Rest controller. You'd be better off centralising this logic into a model for manipulating and querying events.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! That does clarify things a lot. I'm still a bit puzzled on how to handle different requests within one controller in order to handle requests such as http://www.example.com/api/geteventdetails/1234 and http://www.example.com/api/getregistrationdetails/1234 all together... I've elected to go with different controllers for the time being, and will retro-fit them later as necessary.